# How to calculate a Date for a 00:00:00 a.m. of a today?

Tags: java, calendar

I need to calculate a java.util.Date for a beginning of a today day (00:00:00 a.m. of a today day). Does someone know something better than resetting fields of java.util.Calendar:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Comment: then wrap it in a method called `getTodayAtMidnight()`

Comment: watch out: not every day begins at midnight; some have begun at 1:00 am.

Comment: @KevinBourrillion could you elaborate, if possible with a source ? Which day(s) are you talking about ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't bother about time zones then your solution is ok. Otherwise it's worth to look at JodaTime.

If you eventually decide to switch to JodaTime, then you can use [DateMidnight](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateMidnight.html) class which is supposed to be used in your situation.

Answer (score 4):

The following code will return the current date's calendar object with time as 00:00:00

```
Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
current.set(current.get(Calendar.YEAR),current.get(Calendar.MONTH),current.get(Calendar.DATE),0,0,0);
```

It will not consider the timezone values and is almost same as your code. Only difference is that it is done all resets to 0 in single line.

Comment: It sets hour to 12 instead of 0

Answer (score 2):

This solution can be better as it does not make use of java's heavy element Calender

```
public class DateTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    long time = dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(new Date())).getTime();
    System.out.println("todays start date : " + new Date(time));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same boat, and what you have provided is how I do it.  I do have it in a `DateUtil.stripToMidnight(...)` function...

But just remember to consider TimeZones when doing all this, as 0:00am here, will not be the same in another part of the world.

There might be a way to do this in JodaTime, but I don't know of it.

Answer (score 1):

With the [date4j](http://www.date4j.net) library :

```
DateTime start = dt.getStartOfDay();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option without additional libraries:

```
import java.sql.Date;

public class DateTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long MS_PER_DAY = 24L * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        long msWithoutTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() / MS_PER_DAY) * MS_PER_DAY;
        Date date = new Date( msWithoutTime );
        System.out.println( date.toGMTString());
    }
}
```

Comment: days are not always 24h long. (hint : daylight saving days)

Answer (score 0):

As of java8, it can be done as follow assuming you don't care about timezone

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), LocalTime.MIDNIGHT);
Date midnight = Date.from(localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```